# Error with CellStatistics arcpy python script

Tags: arcpy, raster, spatial-analyst, cell-statistics, error-999998

I have about 20 raster files in a directory. I want to sum all the rasters into one new raster. The code I wrote was:

```
currentDir=os.getcwd()
tempDir=currentDir+'\\tmp'

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace=currentDir+'\\tmp'
sumRas=arcpy.ListRasters("rr*", "TIF")

outCellStatistics = CellStatistics(sumRas, "SUM", "DATA")
```

When I run it I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "D:\SAPROGtrab\CPIR.py", line 50, in outCellStatistics = CellStatistics(sumRas, "SUM", "DATA") 

File "D:\programas\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 3173, in CellStatistics ignore_nodata) 

File "D:\programas\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs) 

File "D:\programas\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 3169, in Wrapper [function] + Utils.flattenLists(in_rasters_or_constants)) 

RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.
```

If I run it with only 3 raster files it work ok.

Any idea about this error?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.
Added the following line of code.

```
arcpy.env.extent = 'MAXOF'
```